# L'un(e) et l'autre : accord quand on s'adresse à un homme et à une femme

Tags: sens, usage, accord, locutions, écriture-inclusive

Scénario :

Je m'adresse à deux élèves : un homme et une femme.

> Vous devez y réfléchir tous deux. Il faut que vous vous décidiez l'un et l'autre quand vous commencerez votre mémoire.

J'hésite (à l’oral) entre : l'un et l'autre et l'une et l'autre.

De plus, si la phrase fait partie d'un message dois-je écrire :

> Vous devez y réfléchir tous deux. Il faut que vous décidiez l'un.e et l'autre quand vous commencerez votre mémoire.

?

Comment: « Il faut que vous vous décidiez quand … »

Comment: @Personne : C'est noté et corrigé:-)! Merci.

Comment: C'était pourtant correct. On dit "il faut que vous décidiez quand vous commencerez" ou "il faut que vous vous décidiez" tout court, mais pas "il faut que vous vous décidiez quand vous commencerez". "Se décider" n'accepte pas de proposition subordonnée interrogative. (Ou alors il y aussi la forme avec à + infinitif , p.ex. "il faut que vous vous décidiez à commencer").

Comment: J'aurais tendance à dire « l'un et l'autre », si on emploie « l'une et l'autre » cela peut induire que l'on s'adresse à deux femmes. Ce n'est que mon humble avis ...

Comment: Même avis que Toto, instinctivement,  mais sans que je puisse expliquer pourquoi...

Comment: Je pense que c'est parce que quand on s'adresse à un homme et une femme, on a tendance à appliquer instinctivement la règle du "masculin l'emporte" (étant le genre neutre par défaut en français hors écriture inclusive).

Comment: @Greg —  « 1–  Il faut que vous vous décidiez quand vous commencerez votre mémoire » n’a pas du tout le même sens que  «2− Il faut que vous décidiez quand vous commencerez votre mémoire » ; 2  donne la date du début des travaux (quand = à quelle date) 1 vient ensuite à ce moment vous aurez des choix à faire lorsque les travaux seront commencé  induit par « Vous devez y réfléchir tous deux » (quand l’action sera engagée)

Comment: Ok, je comprends alors ce point de vue. La première version de Dimitris indiquait plutôt le sens 1, avec une subordonnée interrogative plutôt que de circonstance de temps.

Comment: Ce n'est pas courant quand il n'y a que deux personnes possibles mais il me semble qu'on peut dire : « Il faut que l'un ou l'une d'entre vous décide quand vous commencerez votre mémoire. »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Étant donné que mon commentaire a reçu un bon accueil, je le transforme en réponse.

J'aurais tendance à dire « l'un et l'autre », si on emploie « l'une et l'autre » cela peut induire que l'on s'adresse à deux femmes.

Dans ce cas, on peut considérer que le masculin fait office de *neutre*

Answer (score 0):

Je crois que le commentaire de l'utilisateur  @Reyedy mérite le statut de réponse :

> Je pense que c'est parce que quand on s'adresse à un homme et une femme, on a tendance à appliquer instinctivement la règle du "masculin l'emporte" (étant le genre neutre par défaut en français hors écriture inclusive).